# Scrapy Xpath extract h6 and ul/li selector in same loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy but I'm running into an issue forming an accurate selector based on scrapy's [tutorial code](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) basically I'm trying to extract all offices within a states state directory and in order to determine which office belongs to what branch of government I need (I think) the what's inside the h6 tag, but also the ul/li elements descending from each one:

This code works fine, and I can save the output of each office to a json for processing later, however it doesn't have the branch above it just an empty space.

```
class NewSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Wyoming'
    start_urls = [
            'http://www.wyo.gov/agencies'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            yield {
                    "Text"     : sel.xpath('a/text()').get(),
                    "Link"     : sel.xpath('a/@href').get(),
            }
```

But (and this is where my inexperience shows) when I adjust it to capture the list header:

```
class NewSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Wyoming'
    start_urls = [
            'http://www.wyo.gov/agencies'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//h6/ul/li'):
            yield {
                    "Hierarchy": sel.xpath('a/name').get(),
                    "Text"     : sel.xpath('a/text()').get(),
                    "Link"     : sel.xpath('a/@href').get(),
            }
```

I'm currently using this [cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/xpath#prefixes) and generally reading up on xpath now since I've read that it's super powerful. But I'm generally kind of confused on how to format the syntax. Please let me know if there is anything I can provide!

Comment: I'm not well-versed with `Scrapy`, but I'm pretty sure it should be `./a/text()`.

Comment: With `//h6/ul/li` you select all `ul` that are INSIDE of an `h6` element. I am pretty sure that there are none.

Comment: @JonasDrotleff your guess is a as good as mine, I was basing the second code snippet based on inspecting the document link in the provided code which shows `<a name="TOC-Executive-Branch---Elected-Officials"></a>` inside the h6 element, but I'm no doubt probably formatting that wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `h6` is not a parent element of `ul`, but it's sibiling. So the best approach in my opinion would be:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for unordered_list in response.xpath('//ul[preceding-sibling::h6]'):
        list_header = unordered_list.xpath('preceding-sibling::h6[1]//font/text()').get()
        rows = unordered_list.xpath('li')
        for sel in rows :
            yield {
                "Hierarchy": list_header,
                "Text"     : sel.xpath('a/text()').get(),
                "Link"     : sel.xpath('a/@href').get(),
            }
```

**Edited:**
My previous XPath was selecting all `ul` for each header. Due to some inconsitencies in the page's html I changed the the selectors to first select the `ul` and then find it's previous `h6` tag that contained it's header. This should work correctly now.

Comment: This works! The only caveat being in the output each office is duplicated with and without the hierarchy so first `{"Hierarchy": null, "Text": "Governor", "Link": "http://governor.wy.gov/"},` appears then the desired output comes once the whole page has been read `{"Hierarchy": "Executive Branch - Elected Officials", "Text": "Governor", "Link": "http://governor.wy.gov/"},`

Comment: Sorry, just checked and there is an issue in the XPath, will fix it in a minute

Comment: @SebastianGoslin I believe it should work as expected now, please let me know. :)

Comment: @rentodvc Works perfectly! Just a heads up the list name is different in the loop but thank you!